# Content not showing in the 'about' page with css

Tags: html, css

When i linked the external css to my ABOUT-US page,the only content that shows is my navbar.any help please?.i tried to unlink the css and all the contents displayed but when i linked the css back,it doesn't work

Comment: Hello! In order for someone to be able help you, you'll need to post your HTML and CSS (preferably a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there are any errors with the browser loading the external css, another thing to check is if there are any errors within the css file that may be causing content to not show and also please make sure the external css path location is correct when retreiving the file.

If this is unknown to you to check if any errors are generated in browser please right click on the page and click inspect, a window on the page should popup and then click on console to view any errors.

I hope this helps

Comment: The navbar i created in the "index.html" is working fine in the "about.html".i can't figure out why the html content is not displaying in the "about" page when i link the css.the html content shows when i take off the css in the "about" page

Comment: I know for sure that the problem is from the css but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser if you inspect the page

Comment: If you are facing this kind of problem so firstly press F12 to inspect the webpage
and check console is there any 404  error or something. It may be a issue sometimes.

Comment: Nothing shows in the console.i've checked several times

Comment: I'll start over and see how it goes